# Selectively interacting with an image in UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I am quite new to HTML,CSS,JS. So please bear my noob questions.

I am working on a UI application.

One of the UI element is a horizontal bar.This bar resides inside a div.This bar contains an image and a name for the image. User can click anywhere on the bar, and a js functionality is invoked(say A).

I now need to add another image to this bar. And when user mouse clicks this image, a js function is to be called(say B). I see an issue here.

As this image is a part of the bar, so clicking it would call A. I need to stop this call, and make sure that only B is called when user clicks this new image.
Clicking on any other part of the bar would still call A.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Could you please provide some actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`e.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) when calling `B` to prevent the event bubbling up to the bars click handler.

```
bOnClick = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Do stuff...
}
```